Difference between the two rules of react hooks
I was reading through their docs and found the below
Rules of hooks:

✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a function component.
✅ Call them at the top level in the body of a custom Hook.
function Counter() {
  // ✅ Good: top-level in a function component
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  // ...
}

function useWindowWidth() {
  // ✅ Good: top-level in a custom Hook
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(window.innerWidth);
  // ...
}

My question is, what is the difference between the first and the second rule. The first rule itself covers what the second rule is telling.

Function component and custom hook are both functions, so the rule to call hooks at the top level of component and custom hook is basically the same in my opinion.
